# html5 cache and android webview with updating in background

Tags: android, html, caching, webview

My challange is to create webapp with Java and html5 for android system.
The app should cache html and any other file, but not for working offline. It is needed for faster app opening next time.

But next time when you open the app, it needs to update this cache in background. How to achive it? Here go the steps I came up with. Tell me how good it is, or isn't.

1. When website will be loaded (whether from the Internet or from cache) and user can use it - in background the cache is cleared.
2. We have webview with loaded website (from cache for example) and empty cache. Good.
3. App opens another/second webview but invisible/in background and with the same website address, so it can be cached again. Then if it is finished, closes itself.

What do you think about it?

Comment: Hi. Have you ever found an answer to your question?

Comment: I've created own cache mechanism for android 4 and above. There is a function that you can override for handling every resource request.

Comment: If its not too much hassle, can't you add it as an answer? Seeing that it did help you and might help others?